# Match any character until you see this string of thee dots

Tags: regex

I have the below data set,

```
    1.1.7 Ensure separate partition exists for /var/tmp (Scored) ...................................... 40
    1.1.8 Ensure nodev option set on /var/tmp partition (Scored) ................................... 42
    1.1.9 Ensure nosuid option set file.ext (Scored) .................................. 43
    1.1.10 Ensure noexec option set on /var/tmp partition (Scored) ............................... 44
    1.1.11 Ensure separate partition exists for /var/log (Scored) ..................................... 45
    1.1.12 Ensure separate partition exists for /var/log/audit (Scored) ......................... 47
    1.1.13 Ensure separate partition exists for /home (Scored) ......................................... 49
1.7.1.7 Ensure the MCS Translation Service (mcstrans) is not installed (Scored)\n
.............................................................................................................................................................. 105
```

I want to extract the number number (x.x.x.x) followed by the text, i.e for the below,

```
1.1.13 Ensure separate partition exists for /home (Scored) ......................................... 49
```

I want group1=1.1.13 , group2=Ensure separate partition exists for /home (Scored)

I can pull out the first group without issues, but I am struggling with the second group as some text contains a . which I want to capture, in addition to this, some lines contain a new line character within the second group so a '.' will not work either, here is my regex,

```
^[ ]?(\d(?:[.]|\d|[ ])+)([^.]+)
```

The issue is within the second capture group ([^.]+), what I am trying to do is 'match everything until you see three dots ...' but it is not working. This is what I have tried without any luck,

```
([^.]{3}+)
(?!\.{3})
```

What should can I do to capture any character until you see the sequence '...' ?

EDIT:

So, I have found a way to do this, but it doesn't feel like it's the best way to do it, here is my regex,

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+(.*?\n?.*?)[\.]{3}
```

So basically, I am saying match anything(apart from a new line) unless you see a new line in that case, match it once, then match everything again until you see '...' . Why does (.|\n)*? not work ?

Comment: You can make an unescaped dot match a newline character, therefor maybe see if [`^\h*(\d+(?:\.\d+){2,3})\h+(.*?)\.{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/pqIVbU/1) works for you.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as it doesn't capture a new line

Comment: It does @rusty009. Just use the right flags as per the link I shared.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the start of the string, followed by optional whitespace chars without a newline and digits with an optional repetition of a dot and digits.

Then match as least as possible chars including a newline till you encounter 3 dots.

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\b([\s\S]*?)\.\.\.
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\S\r\n]*` Optionally match whitespace chars without a newline
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat a `.` and 1+ digits
- `)\b` Close group 1 and a word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[\s\S]*?` Match any char including a newline as least as possible
- `)\.\.\. Close group 2 and match` ...`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J31Rr0/1)

If you want to limit the number of lines following, you can match either as least as possible chars on the same line until you encounter `...` or repeat 1-2 times matching the following lines that do not start with digits, dot and digit and then match `...`

```
^[^\S\r\n]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\b(.*?|.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\d+\.\d).*?){1,2})\.\.\.
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c7yqsC/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
^[ ]?(\d(?:[.]|\d|[ ])+)(.*?)[\.]{3}
```

For spaces, a \s is better:

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+(.*?)[\.]{3}
```

**Edit**: With newline after "(Scored)" or before "..."

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+(.*?)\n?[\.]{3}
```

Comment: Thanks - but this won't work as there are lines with a new line character in them. I will amend the question to reflect this.

Comment: @rusty009 `^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+(.*?)\n?[\.]{3}` with newline after "(Scored)" oder before "...".

Comment: this only works if the new line is before the '...' - how do you capture it even if it isn't ?

Comment: @rusty009 Where can the new lines be everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^([0-9\.]+)\s(((?![.]{3}).)*)
```

Comment: This won't work - doesn't capture new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of greedy consuption you can make use of anchor:

```
^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+(.*?)$
```

In this case "$" matches the Newline (excluding it)
Sources: [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html); [interactive Regex-Check](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: This won't work - doesn't capture new lines.

Comment: With which language do you want to consume the data?
Usually you don't want to keep the newlines in the string.
Depending on your programming language you can also consume the data linewise and match agianst your regular expression, - so check for global and multi-line regex in your PL, maybe :-)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want: `^\s*((?:\d+\.?)+)\s+([^.]*)[\.]{3}`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dxd7Ro/1)